# Find date and time values in text and then update another column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

In postgresql table, I have text column where dates are stored like this:

"Created at 2015-02-12 12:33:33"

or like this:

"Created at 2015-02-14 14:03:42 by Ivan" or "Start date: 2015-02-15 08:44:08"

There is just one date in text but for some row, there isn't date value at all.

example: "Created by Igor"

I need find these date and time values and update another timestamp column with these values.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the date always in ISO format?

Comment: Yes date is always same format just concated with strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

Note: this will work only in case, if date and time values are always in format,  you posted in question.

```
UPDATE your_table SET
datetime_column = 
CASE 
WHEN text_column ~ '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}' THEN regexp_replace(text_column, '.*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*', '\1')::TIMESTAMP
END
```